# Angular 6 - process is not defined when trying to serve application

Tags: javascript, angular, angular6

I am getting the following error when I try to serve my angular 6 application using cosmicjs:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
    at Object../node_modules/cosmicjs/dist/index.js (index.js:6)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../src/app/app.component.ts (main.js:94)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:9)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at Object../src/main.ts (environment.ts:18)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
    at Object.0 (main.ts:12)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:81)
```

My latest theory is something to do with the process.env property being undefined.

I'm following this tutorial [here](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-build-an-angular-js-image-feed-ea6193fa0b75)

and my exact code can be found [here](https://github.com/DanielOram/gallery-app)

The tutorial seems to be using an older version of angular that uses .angular-cli.json instead of the new angular.json and I think this is part of the issue in trying to specify the environment variables.

Answer (score 76):

In `polyfill.ts`, add this line:

```
(window as any).process = {
  env: { DEBUG: undefined },
};
```

Reference: https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-client-javascript/issues/691

---

Or `npm i -S process`, then add this to `polyfill.ts`:

```
import * as process from 'process';
window['process'] = process;
```

Comment: Why would my app randomly need this?

Comment: see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73432010/5053158) for a  possible explanation

Comment: thanks. i had same problem on upgrade to angular13 . resolve by your solution

Answer (score 30):

To fix the problem, I added the following lines to 'polyfills.ts' file,

```
(window as any).global = window;
global.Buffer = global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;
global.process = require('process');
```

Answer (score 10):

This is an incompatibility with Angular v6. They [removed support](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9827#issuecomment-369578814) (shim) of `process` and `global` variables in browser.

I suggest you to use Angular 5, till [cosmic.js](https://github.com/cosmicjs/cosmicjs-node) fixes the error. Maybe you can even open an issue for it.

Comment: Thx for the link to filipesilva comment. It is really useful to understand why this incompatibility exists. The fact is that we SHOULD NOT use a workaround to make 'path', 'fs' or other node modules work in a browser ... we SHOULD just not use them and use polyfills if needed.

Answer (score 9):

This is an incompatibility with Angular 6. They removed support (shim) of process and global variables in browser.

Adding the following before your closing  into your index.html will remove the error.

```
<script>
  var global = global || window;
  var Buffer = Buffer || [];
  var process = process || {
    env: { DEBUG: undefined },
    version: []
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

As long as you are not satisfied with putting some random logic into `polyfills.ts` and looking for a way to actually access the `process.env` in your Angular application please find below solution.

Change your `"builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server"` to `"builder": "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:dev-server"` in `angular.json`.

Comment: Has `process` been removed again? I have this already done for a custom webpack, but I still get `process` errors

Comment: Haven't touched `Angular` for a while already, can't help :(

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue "out of a sudden" in an Angular 14 app.

It turned out I actually introduced it by myself: I forgot to remove a call to `inspect` (from Nodes `util` package) in a service class. Removing the call to `inspect` did the trick for me.

I added the call to `inspect` while debugging Jasmine unit tests. Running unit tests in Jasmine executes the code in Node. This is why it works in that environment.

In `inspect` there is a line

```js
   if ( process.env.DEBUG )
```

Since `process` is not globally defined in the browser, execution of this line fails when running as Angular app.

This type of error is not restricted to `util.inspect` but will happen with any core module from Node running in the browser and accessing internally `process.env`.

Since the internal implementation of the core modules may vary from Node version to Node version, using core modules from Node puts the risk to you application that updating Node on the machine where the deployment build happens can break your application.

"path" is a another candidate that comes to my mind.

Answer (score 0):

if you need to deploy Angular 6 with serve:

polyfills.ts:

```
(window as any).global = window;
global.Buffer = global.Buffer || require('buffer').Buffer;
(window as any).process = {
    env: { DEBUG: undefined },
    version: '', // to avoid undefined.slice error
};
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script>
    if (global === undefined || process === undefined) {
      var global = window;
      window['process'] = {
        env: { DEBUG: undefined },
      };
    }
</script>
```