# Getting process not defined error when connecting angular 5 with ElasticSearch?

Tags: angular, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

It's my first time using angular with elastic and I am getting the above  error on the line "this.client = new Client(//.."

exact error

> ReferenceError: process is not defined
>       at Log.push../node_modules/elasticsearch/src/lib/log.js.Log.addOutput (log.js:213)
>       at new Log (log.js:51)
>       at new Transport (transport.js:19)
>       at new EsApiClient (client.js:58)
>       at new Client (client.js:101)
>       at ElasticsearchService.push../src/app/elasticsearch.service.ts.ElasticsearchService.connect (elasticsearch.service.ts:23)
>       at new ElasticsearchService (elasticsearch.service.ts:18)
>       at _createClass (core.js:9260)
>       at _createProviderInstance$1 (core.js:9234)
>       at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:9200)

Here is the relevant code

```
import { Client } from 'elasticsearch';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class ElasticsearchService {

  private client: Client;

  queryalldocs = {
    'query': {
      'match_all': {}
    }
  };

  constructor() {
    if (!this.client) {
      this.connect();
    }
  }

  private connect() {
    this.client = new Client({
      host: 'http://localhost:9200',
      log: 'trace'
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reinstalling the module solved the issue. Don't know what broke the installation in the first place.

Comment: can you please show me  how you solved the problem and what do you mean "Reinstalling the module solved the issue" and how ? thanks in advance

Comment: Hope it's not late, reinstalling elasticsearch.js should be fine

Answer (score 0):

I Found couple of threads and below command worked for me. [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50313745/angular-6-process-is-not-defined-when-trying-to-serve-application/50313953)

```
 npm i -S process,
```

then add below 2 lines to polyfill.ts file.

```
 import * as process from 'process';
 window['process'] = process;
```