# Angular doesn't have node dependencies after update

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

Updated from Angular 5 to 9. I got the following error in browser devtools:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined

I saw the following post addressing the issue:

[Upgrading to angular-6.x gives "Uncaught ReferenceError: global is not defined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50356408/upgrading-to-angular-6-x-gives-uncaught-referenceerror-global-is-not-defined/50356546)

So I tried to implement the accepted answer's solution and put the following script in my index.html file `<head>` tag:

```
  <script>
    var global = global || window;
    var Buffer = Buffer || [];
    var process = process || {
      env: { DEBUG: undefined },
      version: []
    };
  </script>
```

However, this gave the following error in browser devtools:

> default-encoding.js:6 Uncaught TypeError: process.version.split is not
>   a function

It seems like Angular didn't ship a implementation of process and Buffer to the frontend. Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: Did you follow the link?
https://update.angular.io/#5.0:9.0

Answer (score 0):

Via https://stackoverflow.com/a/50313953/976676:

> This is an incompatibility with Angular v6. They removed support
>   (shim) of process and global variables in browser.

For further clarification: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9827#issuecomment-369578814

Comment: So how does one solve it?