# Angular 11: Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11

I have updated the angular cli and core from 7.1 to 11.0. Updation was successful but after the build getting the below error. Any help will be helpfull thanks.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: process is not defined
at Object.MCLT (vendor.js:207652)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
at Module.tsWA (main.js:32483)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
at Module.kRbw (main.js:27366)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
at Module.x9mp (main.js:34563)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
at Module.cbUm (main.js:22517)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
at Module.PCNd (main.js:15277)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
at Module.NHw6 (main.js:14372)
at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:79)
at Module.3tpA (main.js:4066)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50313745/angular-6-process-is-not-defined-when-trying-to-serve-application

Comment: Yes @OwenKelvin, If I add the below logic in the 'polyfills.ts' then the errors won't come but want to know the reason for the error.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60195988/7908656

Answer (score -2):

There is an official instruction for migration among the Angular version.
It may be helpful if you take a look at it [here](https://update.angular.io/).
Also, keep in mind that you may need to update npm packages.