# Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.feed.load is not a function TypeError: this.feed.load is not a function

Tags: angular, angular10

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbModalConfig, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AppsService } from '../services/apps.service';
import { IApps, Apps, IDataUser, DataUser, IClient, Client, IAppData, AppData } from '../models/apps.model';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
declare var require: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'rss-channel-content',
  templateUrl: './rss-channel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rss-channel.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    AppsService,
    NgbModalConfig,
    NgbModal
  ]
})
export class RssChannelComponent implements OnInit {

  public isGallery: boolean = false;
  public is_view: boolean = false;
  public is_save: boolean = false;
  private id_app: string;
  public structure_app: IApps = new Apps();
  public form_data_user: FormGroup;
  public href: string = '';
  public url: string = '';
  public ocultar: boolean = false;
  public feed = require('rss-to-json');
  public rss: any;
  
  constructor(
    private appsService: AppsService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private modalService: NgbModal,
    private router: Router,
    private spinner: NgxSpinnerService,
    private titleService: Title,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: HTMLDocument
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.spinner.show();
    this.id_app = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.getApplication();
    this.getUrl();
  }
  private getUrl() {
    this.href = this.router.url;
    console.log(this.router.url);
    this.url = this.appsService.getUrl(this.href);
    console.log('url', this.url);

  }

  private getApplication() {
    this.appsService.getApp(this.id_app).subscribe(async (response) => {
      console.log('response', response);
      this.structure_app = response.response.options;
      this.titleService.setTitle(this.structure_app.name_app);
      this._document.getElementById('appFavicon').setAttribute('href', this.structure_app.icono_app);
      this.rss = await this.valueRss();
      this.is_view = true;
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  
  valueRss() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log(this.structure_app.rss_url);
        this.feed.load(this.structure_app.rss_url, function (err, rss) {
        console.log(rss);
        resolve(rss);
      });
      this.spinner.hide();
    });
  }


  /**
   * changeColor
   */
  public changeColor(col: string, amt: any) {
    amt = amt === undefined ? -30 : amt;
    col = col === undefined ? '#eee' : col;
    return this.appsService.changeColor(col, amt);
  }

  public open(e: any) {
    this.modalService.open(e, { centered: true, size: 'lg' });
  }

}
```

explanation:when i call this getApplication api method,inside that method,i am calling valueRSS function,
but its giving this.feed.load is not a function and also giving me process is not defined
i am using angular 10 and rss-to-json version 1.0.5.
basically in that api we have response of rss url,so we are converting that rss url to json data and displaying it to html

Comment: any answer should be appriciated..please help me

Comment: What is this.feed? Where is this property assigned? You are getting the error because this.feed is undefined. anything you call on an undefined will give you the error.

Comment: I think feed is defined as undefined..!!

Comment: @Alvin Saldanha ,public feed = require('rss-to-json');  feed is rss-to-json library

Comment: @AlvinSaldanha  public feed = require('rss-to-json');  its a library i am importing from rss-to-json library

Comment: @AlvinSaldanha feed ,it will convert rss url to json data, coming from the api

Comment: Can you include the code where `this.feed` is set?

Comment: @phuzi yaa its done..can u check now

Comment: Why not just use `HttpClient` ? Values are already in JSON by default and you will not need a library to do this conversion

Comment: @OwenKelvin, yaa i used httpClient in service..but thing is we are retriving json data from api in that api response we have a  rss url ...so we are taking that url and converting the rss-channel url into json data and displaying in html

Comment: Okay, try below 1) `import * as feed from 'rss-to-json'` and in your component `this.feed = feed`

Comment: @OwenKelvin error is gone but its giving me another error core.js:4442 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): ReferenceError: process is not defined
ReferenceError: process is not defined,can u help please

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50313745/angular-6-process-is-not-defined-when-trying-to-serve-application

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the 'rss-to-json' library is compatible  with the  recent versions of Angular. I'm currently on Angular 11.1 and not really able to make it build with that lib included. My guess is that you're also facing some incompatibility issue, where the lib is improperly referenced/loaded, even if (somehow) you've managed to make it build.

So maybe this is not the answer you expect, but my suggestion is to go with [rss-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rss-parser) instead,  which is still usable from Angular.

Here's how it should be added to the project:

1. `npm install rss-parser` (probably you want also to uninstall  rss-to-json)

   `npm install stream`

   `npm install timers`

   I'm not sure why the last two are not automatically added as dependencies when installing rss-parse lib, but the build won't work until we add them.
2. Add the following block inside `package.json`:

```json
"browser": {
   "http": false,
   "https": false
}
```

This lines are needed for avoiding errors related to missing node parts (since we're on browser, we simply say that we don't need/use them).

3. In your code, get rid of the `public feed = require('rss-to-json');` since it won't work like that anymoe. Below you have an example on how rss-parser can be used, via a sample code:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

// Since we need the browser pre-bundled file, we need to
// manually reference it with the absolute path
import Parser from '../../node_modules/rss-parser/dist/rss-parser.min.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  async ngOnInit() {
    const parser = new Parser();
    const feed = await parser.parseURL('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.reddit.com/.rss');

    console.log('received feed', feed);
  }
}
```

There is also a `parser.parseString()` method for parsing a pre-loaded rss feed. Check out the lib's official link I pasted above for more info.

---

As you can see, even with this library it seems that things are a bit clumsy, since we need to do some extra steps, but the up side is that it's compiling and working properly even with the latest version of Angular (v11.1), compared to rss-to-json which doesn't.

Comment: thank u so much for this help its working absolute fine..ur simply awsome thank for ur help..

Comment: I'm glad to hear that, thanks :). If my answer is what you needed in order to solve the issue, please consider accepting it as the actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbModalConfig, NgbModal } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { AppsService } from '../services/apps.service';
import { IApps, Apps, IDataUser, DataUser, IClient, Client, IAppData, AppData } from '../models/apps.model';
import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';
import Parser from '../../../../node_modules/rss-parser/dist/rss-parser.min.js';

declare var require: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'rss-channel-content',
  templateUrl: './rss-channel.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./rss-channel.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    AppsService,
    NgbModalConfig,
    NgbModal
  ]
})
export class RssChannelComponent implements OnInit {

  public isGallery: boolean = false;
  public is_view: boolean = false;
  public is_save: boolean = false;
  private id_app: string;
  public structure_app: IApps = new Apps();
  public form_data_user: FormGroup;
  public href: string = '';
  public url: string = '';
  public ocultar: boolean = false;
  //public feed = require('rss-to-json');
  public rss: any;
  
  constructor(
    private appsService: AppsService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private modalService: NgbModal,
    private router: Router,
    private spinner: NgxSpinnerService,
    private titleService: Title,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: HTMLDocument
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.spinner.show();
    this.id_app = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.getApplication();
    this.getUrl();
    //this.valueRSS();
  }
  private getUrl() {
    this.href = this.router.url;
    console.log(this.router.url);
    this.url = this.appsService.getUrl(this.href);
    console.log('url', this.url);

  }

  private getApplication() {
    this.appsService.getApp(this.id_app).subscribe(async (response) => {
      console.log('response', response);
      this.structure_app = response.response.options;
      this.titleService.setTitle(this.structure_app.name_app);
      this._document.getElementById('appFavicon').setAttribute('href', this.structure_app.icono_app);
      this.rss = await this.valueRss();
      this.is_view = true;
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }


  async valueRss(){
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
      console.log(this.structure_app.rss_url);
      const parser = new Parser();
      await parser.parseURL(this.structure_app.rss_url, function (err, rss) {
      console.log(rss);
      resolve(rss);
    });
    this.spinner.hide();
  });
  }



  /**
   * changeColor
   */
  public changeColor(col: string, amt: any) {
    amt = amt === undefined ? -30 : amt;
    col = col === undefined ? '#eee' : col;
    return this.appsService.changeColor(col, amt);
  }

  public open(e: any) {
    this.modalService.open(e, { centered: true, size: 'lg' });
  }

}
after changing
```

Answer (score -1):

Create another reference to `this` pointer and use in the async calls and callbacks

```
private getApplication() {
    const othis = this;
    this.appsService.getApp(this.id_app).subscribe(async (response) => {
      console.log('response', response);
      othis.structure_app = response.response.options;
      othis.titleService.setTitle(othis.structure_app.name_app);
      othis._document.getElementById('appFavicon').setAttribute('href', othis.structure_app.icono_app);
      othis.rss = await othis.valueRss();
      othis.is_view = true;
    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  async valueRss() {
    const othis = this;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        console.log(this.structure_app.rss_url);
        othis.feed.load(othis.structure_app.rss_url, function (err, rss) {
        console.log(rss);
        resolve(rss);
      });
      othis.spinner.hide();
    });
  }
```

Check if this solves your issue

Comment: i didn't understand ur point...actually when open the module in broswer its giving me process is not defined

Comment: feed.load its directly taking from library its self

Comment: See. every callback function has its own `this` so in callbacks if you are using `this` then it is actually pointing to that callback function and not to the component you are writing the code. Which in turns can't find `feed` in `this` context. I don't know how but in some cases it works just fine but you are lucky in that case.

Comment: I think you got mislead by the indentation, `getApplication` is a completely different scope and `othis` won't be accessible in `valueRss`

Comment: @Kshitij What you're saying makes sense for angular.js, but in Angular zone.js is making sure that the async callbacks are executed in the same context (i.e. NgZone) as the actual angular app. More info [here](https://medium.com/ngconf/deep-dive-into-zone-js-part-1-execution-context-92166bbb957) and [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/zone-js-for-angular-devs-573d89bbb890).